# How to use a bash variable reference to an associative array in a bash function without declaring it before calling that function?

Tags: arrays, bash, pass-by-reference, associative-array

There are multiple ways to get a result from a function in a bash script, one is to use reference variables like `local -n out_ref="$1`, which is also my preferred way.

My bash version is:

```
GNU bash, Version 5.0.3(1)-release
```

Recently, one of my bash functions needed to produce a associative array as a result, like in this example code:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

testFunction() {
    local -n out_ref="$1"

    out_ref[name]="Fry"
    out_ref[company]="Planet Express"
}

declare -A employee
testFunction employee

echo -e "employee[name]: ${employee[name]}"
echo -e "employee[company]: ${employee[company]}"
```

I declare the variable `employee` as an associative array with `declare -A`.

The output is:

```
employee[name]: Fry
employee[company]: Planet Express
```

If I remove the line `declare -A employee`, the output is:

```
employee[name]: Planet Express
employee[company]: Planet Express
```

Is there a way to move the declaration of the associative array into the function, so the user of that function does not need to do it beforehand?

Comment: use `declare -p employee` instead of `echo` to inspect the variable including its attributes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `declare -Ag "$1"` inside the function, so that you declare employee as a global variable.

Comment: If I do `declare -Ag "$1"` inside the function, how can I use that variable, like `out_ref[name]="Fry"` from my example?

Comment: If you call `testFunction` from within a function, the `employee` variable will leak to the global scope instead of the local function scope. Better to just use `local -A employee` in that case.

Comment: In that case you would have to move all `echo` commands to the caller function, like this: https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70kKbE4Y8GCpaUlaboWtxjllBX1kzLz9EGiXFwlqcUlbqV5ySWZ-XkamgrVXJw5-cmJOQq6eQr5pSXxRalptkoqhkpcnFBedF5ibmqsrZJbUSWSYHJ-bkFiXiVQPCAnMS-1RMG1oqAotbhYiauWiwtoXE5qEVZLHBVScwty8itTU7k4kV2CJJyanJGvoJuqoAQTgrjASkGlGlWkVgmbYpjLUNTDBGuxuA8STNDQgoUaAA

Answer (score 3):

Without `declare -A employee`, `employee` is basically treated like an ordinary indexed array. In that context, `name` and `employee` are both undefined variables evaluated in an arithmetic context, so both evaluate to 0.

I'm not entirely sure how `local -n` is implemented (`local -nA` is not allowed to mark the reference as an associative array), but it appears that lacking a "real" associate array to assign to, the value of `employee` is just whatever the last value assigned to *any* key of the reference `out_ref`.  (Probably the same as above: both `name` and `company` evaluate to 0 in the arithmetic context, so you are assigning to `out_ref[0]` twice (and because `out_ref` does not refer to an array-marked name, you are just assigning to `out_ref` itself.)

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on what these better minds have provided, here's a functioning example that shows it in actual use.

```
A() {
  declare -Ag "$1"
  local -n ref="$1"
  ref[A]='in A'
}

B() {
  declare -Ag "$1"
  local -n ref="$1"
  ref[B]='in B'
}

A foo
B foo
declare -p foo
```

Saved and executed as a file named `tst`, here's the run and the output -

```
$: ./tst
declare -A foo=([A]="in A" [B]="in B" )
```

Note the "redeclaration" of the global variable in multiple functions does not impugn the data integrity.

Comment: Thanks for providing those examples!

Comment: I wonder how it might work, if I want to call a function A from another function B which should produce a associative array result. Maybe this isn't possible because you can't declare a local associative array reference via `local -n`.

Comment: the A & B functions above both declare `local -n ref="$1"`, each of which is used to reference the name passed is as an associative array.