# How can I update an associative array inside a function passing it by parameter?

Tags: bash, bash4

I have the following code which reads all the `fields` of a Json file (the path being `PRIVATE_REGISTRATION_FILE` and stores them into an associative array (`PRIVATE_FIELDS`) which I query later in my code:

```
declare -A PRIVATE_FIELDS
for PRICING_FIELD in $(jq -c -r '.fields[]' "${PRIVATE_REGISTRATION_FILE}")
do
  FIELD_KEY=$(jq -r '.label' <<< "${PRICING_FIELD}")
  PRIVATE_FIELDS["${FIELD_KEY}"]=${PRICING_FIELD}
done
```

The problem is that I do this several times with several files, even though the logic is always the same.

Hence, I was thinking to extract this logic into a function but I'm having a hard time passing the map parameter to it.

This is what I attempted:

```
function update_array
{
    FILE_NAME=$1
    eval "declare -A MAP="${2#*=}
    for PRICING_FIELD in $(jq -c -r '.fields[]' "${FILE_NAME}")
    do
        FIELD_KEY=$(jq -r '.label' <<< "${PRICING_FIELD}")
        MAP["${FIELD_KEY}"]=${PRICING_FIELD}
    done
}
```

Which I call like this:

```
declare -A PRIVATE_FIELDS
update_array "myFile.json" "$(declare -p PRIVATE_FIELDS)"
```

However it doesn't work, the map remains empty.

```
echo ${PRIVATE_FIELDS["someKey"]}
>>> (empty)
```

I have tried literally each solution proposed [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069188/how-to-pass-an-associative-array-as-argument-to-a-function-in-bash) but none of them worked. What am I doing wrong?

Bash version: `4.2.46(2)-release`

---

Additional note, the Json file looks like this (apparently the calls to `jq` may be reduced):

```
{
    "name": "Something",
    "fields": [
        {
            "label": "key1",
            "value": "value1",
            "other": "other1"
        },
        {
            "label": "key2",
            "value": "value2",
            "other": "other2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: `$1` inside a function is the first argument passed to it, in your case `"$(declare -p PRIVATE_FIELDS)"` but your code seems to be referring to the first argument of the script.

Comment: @LMC sorry I pasted the wrong example, I've updated my question correctly. Thanks for spotting

Comment: You could use PRIVATE_FIELDS inside the function, no need to create another var.

Comment: @LMC thanks, it worked!! If you write it as an answer I'll accept it

Comment: @LMC sorry, wrote too fast. Indeed it works, but I need to explicitly write PRIVATE_FIELDS in the body of the function, which makes the refactoring useless because I will need to have one function per map I need to update.

Comment: BTW, the `function` keyword is something bash supports for backwards compatibility with pre-POSIX ksh. Better to just use `update_array() {` with no `function` to write code that's going to be more compatible with other POSIX-family shells; see **both relevant entries** in https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete (the first one talks about `function update_array() {`, which isn't compatible with either ksh or POSIX; the second one talks about the `function update_array {` legacy-ksh form).

Comment: A nameref variable will help, and you can declare it in the function to eliminate a lot of that extra structure. c.f. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68167187/how-to-use-a-bash-variable-reference-to-an-associative-array-in-a-bash-function/68168637#68168637

Comment: @PaulHodges, the OP has a bash release too old to support namerefs (hence the answer by glenn not being accepted, and the question being updated to reflect the version they're running).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for the tip, I don't often use Bash so I miss a lot of good practices, it's always good to learn them!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use `declare` in a function, you're actually making the variable **local**. See `help declare` at a bash prompt.

Use a nameref (requires bash version **4.3**+):

```sh
function update_array
{
    local FILE_NAME=$1
    local -n MAP=$2     # MAP is now a _reference_ to the caller's variable
    # the rest stays the same
    for PRICING_FIELD in $(jq -c -r '.fields[]' "${FILE_NAME}")
    do
        FIELD_KEY=$(jq -r '.label' <<< "${PRICING_FIELD}")
        MAP["${FIELD_KEY}"]=${PRICING_FIELD}
    done
}
```

then you simply pass the array **name**

```sh
declare -A PRIVATE_FIELDS
update_array "myFile.json" PRIVATE_FIELDS

declare -p PRIVATE_FIELDS
```

---

To more efficiently iterate over the JSON file:

```sh
$ jq -c -r '.fields[] | "\(.label)\t\(.)"' file.json
key1    {"label":"key1","value":"value1","other":"other1"}
key2    {"label":"key2","value":"value2","other":"other2"}
```

That's assuming the labels don't contain any tab characters.

---

Using that, plus your older bash version, you can do this

Assuming that the result arrays will be in the **global** scope

```sh
update_array() {
    local filename=$1 varname=$2
    local -A map
    while IFS=$'\t' read -r label json; do
        map[$label]=$json
    done < <(
        jq -c -r '.fields[] | "\(.label)\t\(.)"' "$filename"
    )
    eval declare -gA "$varname=$(declare -p map | cut -d= -f2-)"
}
```

You'd call it like

```sh
$ echo $BASH_VERSION
4.2.45(1)-release

$ update_array tmp/file.json myArray

$ declare -p myArray
declare -A myArray='([key2]="{\"label\":\"key2\",\"value\":\"value2\",\"other\":\"other2\"}" [key1]="{\"label\":\"key1\",\"value\":\"value1\",\"other\":\"other1\"}" )'

$ for label in "${!myArray[@]}"; do
>     printf '"%s" => >>%s<<\n' "$label" "${myArray[$label]}"
> done
"key2" => >>{"label":"key2","value":"value2","other":"other2"}<<
"key1" => >>{"label":"key1","value":"value1","other":"other1"}<<
```

Comment: Show the JSON data, we can reduce the number of times you need to call out to `jq` to once.

Comment: Get out of the habit of using ALLCAPS variable names, leave those as
reserved by the shell. One day you'll write `PATH=something` and then
[wonder why](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27555060/7552) 
your [script is broken](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28310594/7552).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! About the naming, thanks for the tip. I'm a very occasional bash scripter, I don't really know the good practices :) About the Json, I'll update my question to show it. Then I'll try your solution and let you know if it worked, thanks again!

Comment: I see your bash version, I'll update my answer shortly

Comment: Thanks a lot not only for the perfectly working solution but also for the nice tips, my script really looks much more beautiful now :)