# How to assign an associative array from a string in a function

Tags: bash, function, associative-array

I want to populate an associative array with successive output from an instruction.

With attention for the [quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39418782), I first tried this

```
declare -A aa
dict='[TAG1]="VALUE 1" [TAG2]="VALUE 2"'
aa="( ${dict} )"
dict='[TAG3]="VALUE 3" [TAG4]="VALUE 4"'
aa+="( ${dict} )"
declare -p aa
```

but the variable content is not split in keys and values:

```
declare -A aa=([0]="( [TAG1]=\"VALUE 1\" [TAG2]=\"VALUE 2\" )( [TAG3]=\"VALUE 3\" [TAG4]=\"VALUE 4\" )" )
```

While a more explicit version works as expected:

```
declare -A aa
aa=( [TAG1]="VALUE 1" [TAG2]="VALUE 2" )
aa+=( [TAG3]="VALUE 3" [TAG4]="VALUE 4" )
declare -p aa
```

So I used a workaround

```
dict='[TAG1]="VALUE 1" [TAG2]="VALUE 2"'
declare -A aa="( ${dict} )"
dict='[TAG3]="VALUE 3" [TAG4]="VALUE 4"'
declare -A aa+="( ${dict} )"
declare -p aa
```

that delivers the expected result:

```
declare -A aa=([TAG4]="VALUE 4" [TAG1]="VALUE 1" [TAG3]="VALUE 3" [TAG2]="VALUE 2" )
```

Now my ultimate goal was to update an associative array in a function, the array being an argument to the function. [Passing the array by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68168637), it should look something like this

```
modaa () {
declare -Ag "$1"
local -n ref="$1"

dict='[TAG1]="VALUE 1" [TAG2]="VALUE 2"' # In reality, this is the output of an instruction, i.e. $(lsblk -P ...)

ref+="( ${dict} )"                  # NOK: Assign "$dict" to key [0]
# declare -A ref+="( ${dict} )"     # No effect
# declare -Ag ref+="( ${dict} )"    # No effect
# ref+=( [TAG1]="VALUE 1" [TAG2]="VALUE 2" )    # Always works but does not use $dict
echo "${!ref[@]}"
}
```

But because of the issue explained above, the simpler expression doesn't work:

```
declare -A aa
modaa aa
declare -p aa

declare -A aa=([0]="( [TAG1]=\"VALUE 1\" [TAG2]=\"VALUE 2\" )" )
```

and the workaround of using 'declare' each time to update does not work within a function.

Did I miss something or is the solution to parse $dict and assign key/value pairs one by one?

Comment: within the function, where is `${dict}` comming from? is supposed to be arg #2 (`$2`) or does the function just *assume* the caller has defined `${dict}`? please update the question with a few sample calls to the function to include the `${dict}` values and the results following each function call (eg, output from `declare -p array`)

Comment: In my example function `dict` is global, but in my actual script it is defined within the function as the output of an instruction like `$(lsblk -P -o name,path,uuid,partuuid,mountpoint | grep -e "${dexp[UUID]}" | sed -E -e 's/([[:alnum:]]+)=/\['"${dexp[ID]}"',\1\]=/g' - )` I did not think it relevant and my question was already quite long.

Answer (score 0):

It seems we cannot use the `declare -A ref="( $str )"` or
`local -A ref="( $str )"` syntax with the references.
Alternatively how about expanding the string into a temporary array variable:

```
#!/bin/bash

modaa () {
    declare -Ag "$1"
    local -n ref="$1"
    local -A temp="( $2 )"
    local key
    for key in "${!temp[@]}"; do
        ref[$key]=${temp[$key]}
    done
}

modaa "aa" '[TAG1]="VALUE 1" [TAG2]="VALUE 2"'
declare -p aa
```

Output:

```
declare -A aa=([TAG1]="VALUE 1" [TAG2]="VALUE 2" )
```

Another option may be to use `eval`, although we should avoid using
`eval` as much as possible:

```
#!/bin/bash

modaa () {
    eval "$1=( "$2" )"
}

modaa "aa" '[TAG1]="VALUE 1" [TAG2]="VALUE 2"'
declare -p aa
```

As you know `eval` has severe security risks. Please make sure the
variables passed to `eval` are fully under control without any chance
of tampering by others.

Comment: I would definitely want to avoid eval and I would resort to creating a temporary variable and looping through the key/value pairs if I have to. It just seems odd that the issue could be solved by using a form that should work `ref+=" ${dict}"` and it just doesn't and I don't see why.

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

- format of the data in the `$dict` variable is always of the form `[index]="value string"` where ...
- there are no equal signs (`=`) nor linefeeds embedded in `"value string"`

One idea using a nameref for the array:

```
modaa () {

# Usage:
#         modaa array_name [index1]="string1 value"
#         modaa array_name [index1]="string1 value" ... [indexN]="stringN value"

local -n ref=$1                                # array_name
shift

while IFS='=' read -r ndx val
do
    ndx="${ndx//[][]/}"                        # remove '[]' characters
    val="${val//\"/}"                          # remove double quotes

    ref+=( [${ndx}]="${val}" )                 # create array entry

done < <(sed 's/"[[:space:]]/"\n/g' <<< $@)    # break multiple [index]="string value" entries into separate lines

}
```

Taking the function for a test drive:

```
unset      aa bb
declare -A aa bb

dict='[TAG1]="VALUE 1"'
modaa aa "${dict}"

dict='[TAG2]="VALUE 2"'
modaa bb "${dict}"

dict='[TAG3]="VALUE 3"'
modaa aa "${dict}"

dict='[TAG5]="VALUE 5" [TAG6]="VALUE 6"'
modaa bb "${dict}"
```

Results:

```
$ declare -p aa bb
declare -A aa=([TAG1]="VALUE 1" [TAG3]="VALUE 3" )
declare -A bb=([TAG2]="VALUE 2" [TAG5]="VALUE 5" [TAG6]="VALUE 6" )
```

Comment: Parsing $dict and assigning key/value pairs one by one would obviously work and the proposed code seems an elegant implementation. My question really was about why aa="( ${dict} )" doesn't do what one would expect to do and if there is really no way to fix it, rather than working around it.